# How to verify immediately if Google Analytics content grouping is working or not

Tags: google-analytics

I have created Google analytics content grouping in analytics admin panel by using the tracking code method.

1. I have created my first group with name "Product Detail Pages" inside "Content Grouping Settings" whose index is 1.
2. I have created my second group with name "Category Pages" inside "Content Grouping Settings" whose index is 2.

I double confirmed that both are ON. Then in the code from the product detail pages I have added

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'MY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE']);
        _gaq.push(['_setPageGroup', '1', 'Product Detail Pages']);            
        _gaq.push (['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

It simply does not work. Google Analytics (inside Google Analytics admin panel, Behaviour -> Overview -> Site Content -> Product Detail Pages (content group) ) simply shows me zero page views (and (Not Set) also ) since many weeks.

What did I do wrong? Is there any way to verify  if this grouping works or not?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing *Product Detail Pages* as the Group for your Content Grouping? If so, that will be the only group showing up in your report.

You can check to see if the content group is firing by using an extension such as [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) (Chrome) or [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) (Firefox), and look for the content group parameter in the request.

If you want to share the site, we can take a look too.